# Rotate Array, python challenge

Tags: python

QUESTION :Given an integer array nums, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.
Example 1:

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, nums, k):
         x = len(nums) - k
         return nums[x:] + nums[0:x]
```

WHY IS MY FUNCTION DOES NOT WORK ON LEETCODE, BUT ITS WORKING JUST FINE ON VSCODE.
FOR ROTATING ARRAY.

Comment: `k` can be larger than `len(nums)`. Does your code work correctly in that case?

Comment: What happens when k=0?

Comment: The instructions say to rotate in place. The function is not supposed to return anything.

Comment: share the link of question for better understanding, we do not input cases.